# How to express codomain consisting of tuples?

Tags: functions

I'd like to describe the codomain of a function $f$.

$f$ takes $t\in T$ and returns two tuples $x = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2, ..., y_m)$, whereas $x_i \in X$ and $y_i \in Y$

The size of $x$ and $y$ depends on $t$, meaning that $n$ and $m$ are no fixed number. In my case, however, the maximum value of $n$ is 7 and the maximum value of $m$ is 9.

I am wondering how to describe the codomain of $f$. I doubt this would make sense:

$f: T \rightarrow (X^n \times Y^m)$

because this probably implies that $n$ and $m$ are fixed numbers.

How to I express the codomain of $f$ correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your question concerns the codomain of $f$ (not the domain, which is just $T$).

For nonnegative integer $n$ and set $X$ there is a notation $X^{\leq n}$ where:$$X^{\leq n}:=\bigcup_{k=0}^nX^k$$

So here you could go for codomain:$$X^{\leq 7}\times Y^{\leq 9}$$

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the codomain. Sorry. The codomain would then be $X^{\leq n} \times Y^{\leq m}$?

Comment: No, it would be: $X^{\leq 7}\times Y^{\leq 9}$. A codomain with parameters $n,m$ in it is not desirable.